# How to add a row from a table to another table in Jupiter

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook, append

Suppose table A has 4 rows and 5 columns
and table B has 2 rows and 5 columns

How can I select first row from table B and add it to table A?

I am using pandas

Comment: Consider describe a litltle bit more.  Are you using __pandas__ ?  If so, please add the pandas tag to your post.

Comment: yes, I am using pandas

Comment: Please, edit your post and give sample data and expected output;

Comment: you can use your own example

Comment: Consider check as the anser if the code answer your question. :)

Comment: look at my example in 2nd answer

Comment: I have updated.  Consider upvote and mark as an answer if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```py
import pandas as pd
dict_1 = {'A': ['ww', 'qq', 'xx', 'tt', 'bb'],'B': [1, 71, 34, 2, 3],'C': [2, 87, 42,35,4],'D': [713,265,12,1,1],'E': [65,24 ,22 ,1 ,1]}
dict_2 = {'Counts': ['Female', 'Male', 'Total'],'A': [5,2,2],'B': [80,81,89],'C': [2,2,3],'D': [12,8,1],'E': [93,7,8]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
```

Insert a new Column on df_1:

```py
df_1.insert(0, "Counts", '-')
```

Get the Last Line of DataFrame 02

```py
line = df_2.iloc[-1:]
```

Append to the last line to the first dataframe

```py
df_1 = df_1.append(line, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Counts  A    B  C   D   E
0   -      ww    1  2   713 65
1   -      qq   71  87  265 24
2   -      xx   34  42  12  22
3   -      tt   2   35  1   1
4   -      bb   3   4   1   1
5   Total   2   89  3   1   8
```

Comment: look at example answer I added and see if you join those tables